# Matplotlib displaying weird line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw rectangle on matplotlib, each layer should have different color:

My code:

```
width = 416
height = 416
heatmap = np.zeros((width,height),dtype='float')
```

Initialize array full of zeros

```
box = [60,50,100,100]
```

Box i want to draw

```
while box[0] < box[2]:
    width = box[2] - box[0]
    height = box[3] - box[1]
    for i in range(width):
        heatmap[box[1]][box[0] + i] = value
        heatmap[box[3]][box[0] + i] = value
    for j in range(height):
        heatmap[box[1] + j][box[0]] = value
        heatmap[box[1] + j][box[2]] = value

    value = value + 0.1
    box[0] += 1
    box[1] += 1
    box[2] += -1
    box[3] += -1
plt.imshow(heatmap)
plt.show()
```

And my code for drawing it, basicly it will draw spirale, however when i print it[image]
There is weird black line, what is it doing there and how did it get there?

Also when i wanted to save the iamge

```
plt.imsave("name.png", heatmap.astype('uint8'), cmap=matplotlib.cm.gray, vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

It saves black image, why is this happening?

Thanks for help.

Comment: If you want to draw a spiral instead of a pyramid like thing you should rethink the loops in your code.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: from your question it is difficult to understand what you want to draw: rectangles or a spiral (".. basicly it will draw spirale, however ..."). Can you make it a bit more clearer what you want to draw?

Answer (score 0):

Doing just one more iteration in one of your loops (here over width) fixes this :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
width = 416
height = 416
heatmap = np.zeros((width,height),dtype='float')
box = [60,50,100,100]
value = 0
while box[0] < box[2]:
    width = box[2] - box[0]
    height = box[3] - box[1]
    for i in range(width+1):
        heatmap[box[1]][box[0] + i] = value
        heatmap[box[3]][box[0] + i] = value
    for j in range(height):
        heatmap[box[1] + j][box[0]] = value
        heatmap[box[1] + j][box[2]] = value
    value = value + 0.1
    box[0] += 1
    box[1] += 1
    box[2] += -1
    box[3] += -1
plt.imshow(heatmap)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your 2nd question, about the black image:

The maximum value of heatmap is 1.9, see `heatmap.max()`.

The maximum value of the values you use for the image is 1, see `heatmap.astype('uint8').max()`.

If you change `vmax` to 1 in your `imsave` call you get a white box instead of an almost black box.